# Need help converting batch to bash

Tags: bash, batch-file

So I have been trying to convert my batch file to bash. I am running a linux (ubuntu) server and I want to run my game server off there instead of my work/play machine. Here is the bash

```
@echo off
title BSH 525
cd ../build 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -server -cp .;../deps/*; net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
pause
```

and here is my attempt at the bash

```
!/bin/bash
cd ../build 
java -server -cp .;../deps/*; ../net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
```

I keep getting errors such as files not found, or java is complaining about syntax

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- The first line should read:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  with a leading `#`. This is special syntax which tells the kernel which shell should be used to run your script.
- In Unix, paths are separated with `:` in Java classpath, rather than `;`. So try:

  ```
  java -server -cp .:../deps/* ../net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
  ```

  The `;` is actually a command separator, so the shell was treating your single line as three different commands.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the directory separator is `:` instead of `;`

```
java -server -cp .:../deps/*: ../net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems:

```
!/bin/bash
cd ../build 
java -server -cp .;../deps/*; ../net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
```

The [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line is incorrect; it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You've got a `cd ../build` -- but what was the current working directory *before* you execute this script? You must get that correct -- or use an absolute directory instead, such as:

```
cd ~/gameserver/build
```

And, the path separator for *lists of directories* on Unix-like systems is `:` instead of `;`. So your Java command should instead look like:

```
java -server -cp .:../deps/*: ../net/com/codeusa/Server 43595
```

(Though I'm surprised about that blank directory at the end of the class searchpath...)

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I would have pulled every hair out of my head if it was not for all of your help. I am beginning to like the unix kernal. It is very different from Windows (<- rhetorical statement) but I like the computing power and security.